# Terminating raw_input based on the ascii value of the string

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to python.
My Issue- **need to terminate the raw_input if no input is passed**
I am basically asking user for number of key-value pairs to be added to dictionary. Then adding the key-value pairs in dictionary. Later querying the dictionary which should result value if key exist, else print `Not found`.

I searched the Stack Overflow and found solution in terms of timer but I am trying to use ord function to get ascii value of string and check it against null that is ascii value of 0. My code does not seem to terminate, please advice on necessary changes in code.

Please find the code that I am using in the program:

```
def convert_to_ascii(text):
    return "".join(str(ord(char)) for char in text)


n=int(raw_input().rstrip())
phonebook = dict(raw_input().split() for i in range(n))
print phonebook


list1=[]
while True:
     choice = raw_input()
     temp=convert_to_ascii(choice)
     print temp
     if temp != '0':
        list1.append(choice)
     else:
         break

for word in list1:
    if word in phonebook :
       print '{0}={1}'.format(word,phonebook[word])
    else:
        print 'Not found'
```

Comment: Please format code using the tools provided. This site is not about getting help for small programs, but for specific programming questions. What is the question here? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have the empty string `''` instead of `'0'` as your check. This code worked for me. I also added some prints in the raw_inputs to help me look through your code, but the only change that matters is the `'0'` to `''`:

```
def convert_to_ascii(text):
    return "".join(str(ord(char)) for char in text)


n=int(raw_input('How many entries in your phonebook?\n').rstrip())
phonebook = dict(raw_input('Please enter "[name] [number]" for entry '+str(i+1)+':\n').split() for i in range(n))
print phonebook


list1=[]
while True:
     choice = raw_input('Who do you want to choose?\n')
     temp=convert_to_ascii(choice)
     if temp != '': #<-- changed to empty string from '0'
        list1.append(choice)
     else:
         break

for word in list1:
    if word in phonebook :
       print '{0}={1}'.format(word,phonebook[word])
    else:
        print word,'was not found'
```